# Grab a number from a string

Tags: c++, string, double, extract

I'm trying to write a C++ program which takes input from a vector called myvec (each line is one string like shown below) where the lines look like this:

```
<wgt id='1001'> 0.32365E+04 </wgt>
```

And I need to extract the numbers (0.32365E+04 in this case) that always sit in between the > and the <, and put them into a vector  called weight1.

So far I'm pretty lost on how I would do this. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
if(myvec[j].find(...) == 0) {
    weight1.push_back(...)
}
```

But I'm not sure what I would put in these parenthesis.  Is there maybe an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Either [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) or use an XML parser if that is the source of your string in the first place.

Comment: You can find the first '>' in original order and reverse find the first '<', then you can get the string substring between these two indices

Comment: `">\\s*(\\S+)\\s*<"` and get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: Adding on top of the approach by @taocp, you may also want to trim the substring for extra whitespaces.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work perfectly using what @taocp suggested as follows:

```
void strings()
{
    vector <string> myvec;
    vector <double> weight1;
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1001'> 0.12365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1002'> 0.22365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1003'> 0.32365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1004'> 0.42365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1005'> 0.52365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1006'> 0.62365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1007'> 0.72365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1008'> 0.82365E+04 </wgt>");
    myvec.push_back("<wgt id='1009'> 0.92365E+04 </wgt>");

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        weight1.push_back(stod(myvec[i].substr(myvec[i].find('>')+2, myvec[i].rfind('<')-myvec[i].find('>')-3)));
        cout << weight1[i] << endl;
    }       
}
```

With output:

```
1236.5
2236.5
3236.5
4236.5
5236.5
6236.5
7236.5
8236.5
9236.5
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should consider using an iterator to get each items of the vector